# How to Transform X and Y Coordinates to Left and Right Motor Movement

Tags: geometry, language-agnostic, slam

I am trying to implement an EKF Slam to a robot using python. The robot returns an estimate of its current x and y position and an angle (the direction the robot is facing). For my slam however I need this to be left and right motor movements which can be understood as the way a tank is driving: One side is moving more than the other which results in a turning motion.
Is there a formula to calculate l and r from x, y, theta?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually modeled as a differential drive robot. Unfortunately,  there isn't an equation directly relating x, y, and theta to wheel angular excursion (e.g. encoder position) L and R. However,  there is a velocity based relationship,  which can be seen here https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ug/mobile-robot-kinematics-equations.html.

The system is nonholonomic,  which makes designing an observer harder,  but you can use local linear approximations to some degree.